# How to work out which tables Employee is listed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out what tables have entries in them for Employee x. The reason I want to do this is something work for employee y and I think I am missing an entry in one of the tables but don't know which. Is there a general way in sql server to check an employee in the Employee Table and check what other tables hold a value for them? And then do the same for the second employee and then compare ?

So I have Emplyee id 1 in the Employee Tables and what to find out what other tables in the database hold values for him.

Comment: You'll need to know what other tables might have the employee and the name of the employee id column. If the column is named `EmployeeID` in all tables or you have foreign keys referencing the employee table, you could query the catalog views to determine the list of tables/columns and then query each individually.

Comment: I don’t follow, do you know which tables has a reference to the Employee table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the name of the column is the same in all the tables, you can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @tab_name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @rowcount INT
DECLARE @tab_result TABLE(tab_name VARCHAR(100), command NVARCHAR(300), rec_count INT)

DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(100) = 'employee_id'
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50) = '1'

DECLARE c_tables CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Tab.name AS tab_name, 'SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + Tab.name + ' WHERE ' + Col.name + ' = ' + @value AS command
  FROM sys.all_columns AS Col
 INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects AS Tab on Tab.id = Col.object_id
 WHERE Tab.type = 'U'
   AND Col.name = @column_name
 ORDER BY Tab.name

OPEN c_tables
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_tables INTO @tab_name, @command

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK

    EXEC sp_executesql @command, N'@rowcount INT OUTPUT', @rowcount OUTPUT

    IF @rowcount > 0
        INSERT INTO @tab_result VALUES (@tab_name, @command, @rowcount)
END
CLOSE c_tables
DEALLOCATE c_tables

SELECT *
  FROM @tab_result
 ORDER BY [@tab_result].rec_count DESC
```

Just set the values of the variables ***@column_name*** and ***@value*** according to your needs.

Comment: "Considering that the name of the column is the same in all the tables", how do you know that when nothing like that is stated in the question?

Comment: You're right. I should've say "If the column name is the same". Otherwise  it would be necessary to dig deeper into the system tables and find the foreign keys.